# Check if rename operation replaced an existing file in minifilter driver

Tags: filesystems, driver, minifilter

When a file is being renamed or moved, the API allows to overwrite the destination file if it already exists. I can observe that event in a minifilter by checking the `FLT_IO_PARAMETER_BLOCK` for

```
Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION
```

and

```
Iopb->Parameters.SetFileInformation.FileInformationClass == FileRenameInformation
```

I can also see that `ReplaceIfExists` was set in the `FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION` struct. Is it also possible to somehow check, if the operation actually caused an existing file to be overwritten?

For `IRP_MJ_CREATE`, the `Information` field in the `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` is set to `FILE_OVERWRITTEN` in the post operation callback if a file has been overwritten. Does something like that also exist for renaming/moving?

Comment: if look for src code of FatSetRenameInfo - unfortunatelly no. IoStatus.Information == 0 in both case. may be only solution in pre-operation check, are target file exist

Comment: That is actually a good idea, i'll do that for now. Thx!